# Setting external ip on VM instead of internal

Tags: google-compute-engine

I currently got a GCE vm, and by default I got a internal IP, and a external IP. The internal is configured on the machine, and external is setup with firewall configurations.

Trying to setup cPanel on this server, it always referes to the internal ip.

Is it possible to run GCE with the external IP on the instance/VM?

Thanks /Fredrik

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no way to map an external IP address to a GCE instance directly.  All communication is NATed to the internal address.

You can, however, access the external address programmatically via the metadata server:

```
http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip
```

I've never set up cPanel so I can't give you any guidance there.